# functions shall not be declared at block scope

Tags: c++, misra

I couldn't able to understand the following misra rule, " functions shall not be declared at block scope " . the explanation given in the document is "A function declared at block scope will refer to a member of the enclosing namespace, and so the declaration should be explicitly placed at the namespace level." What they mean by will refer to member of enclosing namespace? Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that when you have this, `foo` will have its definition outside of `bar`, in the namespace:

```
namespace {
    void bar() {
        void foo();
    }

    //could define foo here
}
```

What it's saying is to just move the declaration out to the same level as the definition:

```
namespace {
    void foo();

    void bar() {}

    //could define foo here
}
```